# Android - MediaRecorder Transformation Matrix before save to file

Tags: android, video, android-camera2, android-mediacodec, android-mediarecorder

I am using MediaRecorder and Camera2 api to record video to a file. I would like to modify the video before saving with a transformation matrix on each frame. I am looking at using MediaCodec for this, but am lost in how exactly the setup would work.

**What is the correct way to record video in Android and apply a transformation matrix on each frame before saving to a file?** (ex: Flip various frames 180 degrees)

Camera->Surface->MediaCodec + Transform->Surface->MediaRecorder->File, or
Camera->Surface->MediaCodec + Transform->File, or
 is there another option I am missing

Answer (score 1):

Unless MediaCodec has a parameter that lets you adjust the transform matrix for each frame, you probably need to have an intermediate step where you edit the image data, either on the CPU or the GPU.

For the former, you'd want
`Camera -> Surface -> ImageReader -> <edit image> -> ImageWriter -> Surface -> MediaRecorder -> file (or MediaCodec -> MediaMuxer -> file).`

For the latter, you'd want
`Camera -> Surface -> SurfaceTexture -> OpenGL ES renderer -> Surface -> MediaRecorder -> file (or MediaCodec -> MediaMuxer -> file).`

It's quite a bit of code to set up the EGL option, but it's very flexible and efficient once you do.

Comment: In terms of efficiency; what does the ImageReader/ImageWriter actually do? Is it just moving buffers? If yes, OpenGL sounds a lot more in-efficient with all the setup and rendering passes involved. I guess this needs to be profiled first, but I was wondering if you have any thoughts on this.

Comment: ImageReader is basically equivalent to SurfaceTexture, and ImageWriter basically equivalent to the GPU's output to the MediaRecorder Surface.  They're just circular queues of graphics buffers, passing them from the producer to the consumer, and then reusing them once consumed.  They all use the same infrastructure under the hood, just with different endpoints and which bits of the underlying system are exposed in their APIs.   Whether a GPU or CPU is better depends on the characteristics of your workload.